# References with text in LaTeX

Tags: latex

In LaTeX you can easily reference a section by using `\label{}` next to a section and then `\ref{}` to create the reference. However, the reference only includes the number of the section, or the page with `\pageref{}`. I would like to insert a reference containing the text of the section.

Example:

```
\section{My Section}
\label{section:my}

This is a reference to Section~\ref{section:my}.
```

The output is the following:

```
1. My Section

This is a reference to Section 1.
```

I would like to have:

```
This is a reference to 1. My Section.
```

Comment: Duplicate. See my answer to [522838](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522838/how-do-i-emit-the-text-content-of-a-reference-in-latex/522893#522893).

Comment: not to sound like an ass, but having the whole block of text that you are cross referencing kind of defeats the purpose of a cross reference...

Comment: There's also [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com) now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I emit the text content of a reference in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522838/how-do-i-emit-the-text-content-of-a-reference-in-latex)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Have a look to this wiki: [LaTeX/Labels and Cross-referencing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#The_hyperref_package_and_.5Cnameref.7B.7D):

> The **hyperref** package automatically includes the **nameref** package, and a similarly named command. It inserts text corresponding to the section name, for example:

```tex
\section{MyFirstSection}
\label{marker}
\section{MySecondSection} In section \nameref{marker} we defined...
```

Answer (score 24):

I think you can do this with the [`hyperref`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) package, although I've not tried it myself. From the relevant [LaTeX Wikibook section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing):

> The `hyperref` package introduces another useful command; `\autoref{}`. This command creates a reference with additional text corresponding to the targets type, all of which will be a hyperlink. For example, the command `\autoref{sec:intro}` would create a hyperlink to the `\label{sec:intro}` command, wherever it is. Assuming that this label is pointing to a section, the hyperlink would contain the text "section 3.4", or similar (capitalization rules will be followed, which makes this very convenient). You can customize the prefixed text by redefining `\typeautorefname` to the prefix you want, as in:
>
> `\def\subsectionautorefname{section}`

Comment: Or consult the `hyperref` manual here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/nameref.pdf

Comment: @Paul The link is broken.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/nameref?lang=en is the place to go to find all the docs of the `nameref` LaTeX package. From there onde can download the PDF of the documentation in a suitable mirror next to your Internet location.

Answer (score 16):

Using the `hyperref` package, you could also declare a new command by using `\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\autoref{#1}. \nameref{#1}}` in the pre-amble. Placing `\secref{section:my}` in the text generates: *1. My section.*

Comment: Don't know why, but placing this in the pre-amble of template I use just **broke** Overleaf compiling