# Referencing a theorem-like environment by its [name]

Tags: latex

I am using ntheorem to typeset a set of conditions. In my preamble I have:

```
\theoremstyle{empty}
\newtheorem{Condtion}{Condtion}
```

When I want to typeset a condition, I write:

```
\begin{Condtion}[name]
\label{cnd:nm}
foo foo foo
\end{Condition}
```

The name appears boldface on the same line as the start of the text of the condition, with no number or anything. Perfect.

What I want to do now is refer to the condition by some variant of the `\ref` command,
\ref calls the number [which is not displayed anywhere else]
\thref writes "Condition n" for the nth condition
\nameref writes the name of the SECTION of the label. 
a zref solution was suggested [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/227d1a4a9e546696#), but seems unsatisfactory and unwieldly.

Any suggestions on a simple way to do this? (Even a simpler zref solution would be nice) At the moment I've just defined a `\newcommand` for each condition and use that rather than citing the condition itself. This is semantically opaque and just unsatisfying...

(edit: I emailed one author of ntheorem, Wolfgang May, and he explained that there isn't really a way to do this within ntheorem, since the [name] option isn't recorded.)

(edit: This isn't a dupe as suggested in the comment, since I'm interested in referencing an environment by its optional name command, not referencing the section/chapter it sits in.)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491842/references-with-text-in-latex which *might* be an effective duplicate. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613506/ref-chapter-name-in-latex and things link from there.

Comment: zref could work, but it seems like an awfully complicated way of doing things. I mean, the [name] is already declared at the start of the environment. I just want to call it by its name not its number...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the following may do what you want.

```
\makeatletter
\def\namedlabel#1#2{\begingroup
   \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
   \label{#1}\endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Then you use it as

```
\begin{theorem}
  \namedlabel{thm:seamus}{Seamus' Theorem}
  Here is Seamus' Theorem.
\end{theorem}

Here I reference~\ref{thm:seamus}.
```

Unfortunately, it can then only be referenced by name, though I suppose you could use a normal `\label` as well (with a different key of course).

For the `amsthm` environments you can use

```
\makeatletter
\let\@old@begintheorem=\@begintheorem
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
  \gdef\@thm@name{#3}%
  \@old@begintheorem{#1}{#2}[#3]%
}
\def\namedthmlabel#1{\begingroup
   \edef\@currentlabel{\@thm@name}%
   \label{#1}\endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: That kind of works. But it still isn't ideal. The point is, I want to use the content of the optional argument of the condition as the name I am calling. So I have `\begin{Condition}[Cnd Name]` and I want to have a label that will, when I `ref` it, say "Cnd Name", in bold as it is when the condition is first written out. This way, I have to add an extra argument to the label and make sure it matches "Cnd Name"...

Comment: That's going to depend on the environment used.  You'll probably have to create a wrapper for each such environment, since most of them probably don't save that information anywhere.  If all you want is for the amsthm environments, I have added that to the answer.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll try this out later. Will a similar thing work for ntheorem?

Comment: `\newenvironment{condition}[2]{\begin{Condition}[#1] \namedlabel{#2}{#1} }{\end{Condition}}`

This environment allows me to do what I want, when coupled with your namedlabel fix! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> nameref doesn't work: it references the title of the SECTION the theorem-like environment appears in.

This is a **nameref bug** that was already fixed a while ago:
http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/9uUx5EuqoCGynIvx3om7#lY2MJxvge2oMgOi

Unfortunately some Linux distros like Debian/Ubuntu ship with horribly old versions of the packages (Ubuntu 11.04 still ships TeX Live 2009 although the latest version is TeX Live 2011). If you're using such a Linux distro stop using the Tex Live package in the distro, and install TeX Live directly from here: http://www.tug.org/texlive/  You can then update packages using tlmgr (a really cool tool that doesn't ship with Debian/Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

you may want to check out the [`nameref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nameref) package, which is distributed with `hyperref`. There is a section in the `nameref` documentation about referencing "stuff".

More on referencing can be found in the TeX FAQ item [Referring to things by their name](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nameref).

Comment: nameref doesn't work: it references the title of the SECTION the theorem-like environment appears in. Am checking out other possibilities found in the possible dupes of the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I thought others might find this helpful. Even though I had an updated `hyperref` package installed, I had to explicitly call `\usepackage{nameref}` after `\usepackage{hyperref}` in order to get the correct behavior from `\nameref`. Without the explicit call to `\usepackage{nameref}`, `\nameref` worked, but exhibited the bug discussed in this thread.

Update: this workaround isn't requred for a minimal example (which I checked). I don't know if there's something more complicated going on in my style files, but I'll update this if I find something. This may still help someone running into the same issue I was.

Comment: didnt work for me on windows texstudio with miktex fully updated