# Reference name of description list item in LaTeX

Tags: list, latex, list-definition

I'd like to refer to a description list item by name instead of number. To that effect, I've added labels to each item, but when referencing them I only get the name of the section, not of the list item. How can I change it to show a custom label for each item?

```
\section{Definitions}
\begin{description}
    \item [Vehicle\label{itm:vehicle}] Something
    \item [Bus\label{itm:bus}] A type of \nameref{itm:vehicle}
    \item [Car\label{itm:car}] A type of \nameref{itm:vehicle} smaller than a \nameref{itm:bus}
\end{description}
```

The result is something like this:

> **1 Definitions**
>
> **Vehicle** Something
>   **Bus** A type of Definitions
>   **Car** A type of Definitions smaller than a Definitions

I'd like to have the following:

> **1 Definitions**
>
> **Vehicle** Something
>   **Bus** A type of Vehicle
>   **Car** A type of Vehicle smaller than a Bus

An alternative solution would be to use subsections *and display them as a definition list*. Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: The TeX Stackexchange is now in beta:  http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting. Can I just copy this over verbatim?

Comment: There is no migration to StackExchange sties at this time, so re-posting would be your only option for getting it there. This question *is* on topic here, too. The advantage of using the dedicated site would be a better chance of attention from more and more expert eyeballs.

Comment: [Reposted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/reference-name-of-description-list-item-in-latex-repost) to LaTeX site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be trickier than it sounds. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767389/referencing-a-theorem-like-environment-by-its-name) is in a similar vein and the answer there was disappointingly longwinded. You'd have thought it would be easier... The same `\namedlabel` approach that worked there might work here?

Comment: Excellent - Do you by any chance know how to avoid the duplication in `\item [Object\namedlabel{itm:object}{Object}] foo` if the label name is always the same as the description list item name?